# I noticed the tools for promotion, tweets, Facebook and G+ are missing. What happened to them?

Tags: support

There used to be some buttons for Facebook, Twitter and G+ promotion on the same page as each question. What happened to those buttons? I found them useful for promoting questions. I will still promote without them, I just wanted to know why they were removed?

Comment: This has nothing to do with this, but would you be interested in writing about this match-up for the blog? (http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/2272/1148) Actually you could write about any match up you wanted, but I figured this one would be along your lines of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sharing buttons were [recently removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136994/where-did-the-sharing-buttons-twitter-g-etc-go) because [a lot of people hated them and few people used them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80880/please-ditch-all-of-the-share-icons-they-give-me-nightmares/136810#136810). In the words of Kevin Montrose, Stack Exchange developer:

> 18 hours of data under the new rules plus historical data of the old scheme, reveals that in fact the share buttons are pointless.
>
> About 90% of the people who bother to share something on Twitter/Facebook/G+ copy/paste, and the amount of traffic referred from social media (to Stack Overflow or any of the Stack Exchange's) is far too small to dedicate that kind of real estate to.
>
> Plus everyone hates share buttons, they are the herpes of the internet.